# What is the purpose of this method on CUIT?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, coded-ui-tests

Does anyone know what is the purpose of the commented class on this code snip in Coded UI tests?

```
namespace CUITe_Training
{

[CodedUITest]
public class CodedUITest1
{
    public CodedUITest1() // < --- what is the purpose of this?
    {
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void CodedUITestMethod1()
    {

    }
}
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are you asking why your test has a constructor, or what a constructor is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the **constructor** for your class and used for object instantiation.

See: [Constructors C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ace5hbzh.aspx)

Also: [Using Constructors (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115.aspx)

> When a class or struct is created, its constructor is called.
>   **Constructors have the same name as the class or struct**, and they usually initialize the data members of the new object.